# Web request not 404 proof and crashes app

Tags: android

I have an app where i read some data from online api every 30sec. I have somewhat secured my app so that it will check if the device is connected to network and data can be trasfered.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

But this does not include situations when i am connected to a network which needs authentification for internet access. Or when you have only local connectivity enabled.
The app tries to get data from that api and it crashes. Here is the request code:

```
 public static JSONObject requestWebService(String serviceUrl) {
    disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        // create connection
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);

        // handle issues
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            // handle unauthorized (if service requires user login)
        } else if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // handle any other errors, like 404, 500,..
        }

        // create JSON object from content
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                urlConnection.getInputStream());
        return new JSONObject(getResponseText(in));

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // URL is invalid
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // data retrieval or connection timed out
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // could not read response body
        // (could not create input stream)
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // response body is no valid JSON string
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

All i need is that this app will not crash. How can i achieve this?

SOLUTION: it needed null check before reading JSON object... it was in different method:

```
public void check(){
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        JSONObject dataZNetu = requestWebService("http://census.soe.com/get/ps2:v2/world_event?type=METAGAME");
        if(dataZNetu != null) {  //THIS WAS THE SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM
            try {
                jsonArray = dataZNetu.getJSONArray("world_event_list");
                for (int i = jsonArray.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    JSONObject tempObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int worldId = tempObj.getInt("world_id");
                    int stateID = tempObj.getInt("metagame_event_state");
                    int eventType = tempObj.getInt("metagame_event_id");
                    int instanceId = tempObj.getInt("instance_id");
                    checkUIchange(worldId, stateID, eventType, instanceId);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add logcat result , So we can check the issue

Comment: One of the things you can do is catch all exceptions, debug through and figure out what exception you need to check for specifically. It will give you the message you need to take care of without crashing your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you are catching the appropriate exceptions, I'm guessing that the crash is in the code that calls this method.

If it tries to do something with the result, without checking for null, that's the problem.

But of course, knowing exactly where it crashes would help.

Comment: Thanx, i guess you are right. Ill check for that null because debugging returns this: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: OK so i have put null check before reading that Json and it works! Thank you very much :D